# Laravel: Error when run Seeder

Tags: php, laravel, data-migration, faker

I get an error when create a table seeder using model factory in laravel 5.3 but I don't know where I'm going wrong here.

[ErrorException]
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in D:\Coding\php\laravel\simple-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 660 and defined

Here is my code:

Model:

```
<?php

namespace app;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'articles';

}
```

Model Factory:

```
$factory->define(app\Article::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker){
  return [
    'title' => $faker->sentences(5),
    'content' => $faker->text(),
    'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
    'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()
  ];
});
```

Migrations:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

ArticlesTableSeeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;
use app\Article as Article;

class ArticlesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
  public function run()
  {
    factory(Article::class)->create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Since laravel 5.3 everything is returning a collection instead of an array. Thats why you have that error. Not really familiar with factory/faker , so not sure where you should add a ->get() or ->all() but that should solve it, if you do that on a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'title' => $faker->sentences(5),` produces array with 5 values. Make var before return and concat there these sentences.

Or `sentences(5, true);` Will produce 5 sentence text for you.

Comment: thanks you so much. I changed it to sentences(5,true) and it work now